# Multiplicity and regular sequences

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, graded-modules

We define *multiplicity* of a module $M$ of dimension $d>0$ as $$e(M) := \operatorname{lc} (P_M) (d-1)!,$$ where $P_M$ denotes the Hilbert polynomial of $M$ and $\operatorname{lc}(P_M)$ its leading coefficient. Equivalently, we have $e(M) = Q_M(1)$, where $HP_M (z) = \frac{Q_M(z)}{(1-z)^d}$ and $HP_M$ is the Hilbert-Poincaré series of $M$.

I can prove that if $I = (f_1, \dots, f_r)$, with $\deg(f_i)=d_i$ and $f_1, \dots, f_r$ is an $M$-regular sequence, then $$e(M/IM) = d_1 \cdots d_r \cdot e(M)$$

> Consider now $R= \mathbb{k}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, $I = (f_1, \dots, f_r)$, with $\deg(f_i)=d_i \geq 2$ and $f_i$ homogeneous. Does it holds the reverse implication, i.e. 
>   $$ e(R/I) = d_1 \cdots d_r \quad \Rightarrow \quad f_1,\dots,f_r \quad \text{is a $R$-regular sequence?}$$

Comment: How do you prove for $r=2$? Yes, I asked also on MO but no answers.

Comment: What you need to observe is how multiplicity behaves under a short exact sequence. When $r = 2$, you could first mod out by $f_1$ and assume $R' = R/ (f)$ is a complete intersection of multiplicity $d_1$. Now use the following short exact sequence $0 \to R'/ (0:f_2 R') \to R' \to R'/ f_2R'$ to argue, under the hypothesis, the image of $f_2$ in $R'$ is regular. Having this and the additional assumption mentioned in @user26857's first comment, you can finish the proof.

Comment: @user26857 I'd go with the additivity of multiplicity. Assume to the contrary that $f_2$ is not regular on $R'$. From the short exact sequence, one has $e(R'/f_2R') \le e(R')$. What remains to show is $\dim R' /f_2 R' = \dim R'$. Since $f_2$ is not regular , it is in an associated prime of $R'$. Since $R'$ is a complete intersection ring, Min $R'$ = Ass $R'$. I did not point out $r=2$ is easy enough, but I did want to point out your comment was insightful. I'm curious how your proof goes.

Comment: @user26857 Well, what you said is correct, but that is not what I used. In your example $\dim R/fR \neq \dim R$, but in the proof $\dim R'/ f_2 R' = \dim R'$. In other words, if $e(R/fR) > e(R)$, then $f$ is not in a minimal prime. See Theorem 14.6   of Matsumura's commutative ring theory.

Comment: @user26857 Then $e(R'/f_2R') > e(R')$ implies that $\dim (R'/f_2 R') < \dim R'$.

Comment: Note that this post was deleted by the OP and later undeleted by [user26857's request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc/16904#16904).

Comment: @user26857: did you read the definition in his book? If I remember it correctly, his definition depends on dimension. In other words, multiplicity is additive on a short exact sequence for the highest dimensional components.

Comment: @user26857 I really don't see why you asked a mod to do that before I read your reply. Also, I don't understand why the mod did it for you without my permission. Anyway if you have the book, please read the definition and first two formulas, 14.1 and 14.2. According to his definiton $e(R'/f_2R')$ is zero since it does not have the same dimension as the other two.

Comment: @user26857 Well, the point is that you initiated the process even before me finishing reading your comment. I have no objection it was not constructive after all your comments deleted. If Matsumura's notation confuses you, then think of it as multiplicities are additive for those that has the highest dimensions. As the original post mentioned, $e(M / fM) = \deg f \cdot e(M)$ if $M$ graded and $f$ homogeneous.

Comment: @user26857 Maybe this article might help, http://www.emis.de/journals/BAG/vol.45/no.1/b45h1scb.pdf. Please take a look at Corollary 2.2.

Comment: @Youngsu The only conclusion I can draw is that *you use a definition of multiplicity which doesn't fit the present question*, otherwise how could you say that $e(R'/f_2R')=0$ when $f_2$ is $R'$-regular (in fact, in this case $e(R'/f_2R')=d_1d_2$, and actually, in the graded case there is no non-zero module having multiplicity $0$) and our discussion was in vain.

Comment: @user26857 I do not agree with you. There is no question about $e(R'/f_2R') = d_1 d_2$ since it was the assumption you imposed for induction hypothesis to work. All I am using is the following, let $R$ be a positively graded Noetherian ring over a field $k$ and $f$ a homogeneous element of $R$. Then $0 \to R/ (0:f) \to R \to R/(f) \to 0$ is exact.

Comment: Since Supp $(R)$ = Supp $(R/(0:f)) \cup$ Supp $(R/(f))$, at least one of $R/(0:f)$ or $R/(f)$ has the same dimension as $R$. Remember the length is additive in an short exact sequence. Also, note that this is graded homomorphism. That means the vector space dimension adds up degreewise, i.e., $\dim_k [R/(0:f)]_n + \dim_k [R/(f)]_n = \dim_k [R]_n$. This implies that the Hilbert polynomials for those three modules add up, i.e., $P_R (n) = P_{R/(0:f)} (n) + P_{R/(f)}(n)$ for $n \gg 0$. This means that the coefficients of the highest degree term on both side are equal.

Comment: Recall that the degree of $P_{M}$ is $\dim(M) -1$ for a graded module $M$. In other words, the highest coefficient of $P_{R(f)}$ may or may not come into play when comparing the highest coefficient in the previous equality depending on the dimension of $R/(f)$.  First, if $f$ is not a zero-divisor, then $\dim R/(f) = \dim R - 1$ and $R = R/(0:f)$. Thus $e(R/(0:f)) = e(R)$. Now, if $\dim R/(f) = \dim R$ (this is the case when $R$ is a complete intersection ring and $f$ is a zero divisor), then $e(R) = e(R/(0:f)) + e(R/(f))$.

Comment: In particular, $e(R) \ge e(R/(f))$. This was used to get the contraction in my argument.

Comment: Also, it was answered positively in Mathoverflow, http://mathoverflow.net/a/178919/22388 without further assumptions we had even thought I did not look into details.